# Why are gays stoned?

Tags: quran, homosexuality

I've read verse [7.81](https://quran.com/7:81) in Islam it says those who commit sodomy need to be stoned.

> And [We had sent] Lot when he said to his people, "Do you commit such immorality as no one has preceded you with from among the worlds? Indeed, you approach men with desire, instead of women. Rather, you are a transgressing people." -- Qur'an [7:80-81](https://quran.com/7:80)

I feel like that’s too harsh. If they sinned, it's between them and Allah. Killing them is too harsh.

Comment: This ruling is also from Allah.

Comment: Stoning adulterer isn't too harsh?

Comment: Where exactly is "the stoning" act? I don't see any stoning act, nor I see any kind of punishment from humans in these verses or some before & after them.

Comment: I tend to read it as an injunction against sexual decadence.

Comment: @kalahari: I haven't read this verse before, and I agree with you there is no support in there that supports stoning as a punishment by a person/people; the question is, is there elsewhere - given this question seems to come up often?

Comment: See [this answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/449/17702) for a very short overview over the punishment for homosexual acts. As with all punishments in Islam, the answer "why is this so" is "because Allah said so"; the question of whether the goal the punishment serves weighed against its severity gives a fair balance is a different one, and if your ethical intuition comes to a different result that Islam, then that doesn't mean someone interpreted the sources wrong; it just means you disagree with some of the ethics of Islam.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds brutal to me too, and I personally am against it.  Stoning, in general, is extremely rare in official practice:

> Out of the world’s forty-nine Muslim-majority states, six retain the punishment in deference to Islamic legal tradition, despite the fact that the Koran, unlike the Bible ([Deuteronomy 22:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2022%3A24&version=ESV)), does not mention it. Of these countries only Iran, which officially placed a moratorium on stoning in 2002 but still gives leeway to individual judges, has actually carried it out. -- [How She Wants to Modify Muslims](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/2015/12/03/ayaan-hirsi-ali-wants-modify-muslims/), Max Rodenbeck

Outside of terrorist organizations, it's hard to find support for stoning.

---

Stoning is not mentioned in the Qur'an; not even the Islam-critical website [WikiIslam](https://wikiislam.net/wiki/Stoning_to_Death) contradicts that.

The section on "Sodomy" in Major Sins by [Al-Dhahabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Dhahabi), which is generally a comprehensive source, does not mention stoning (even in the subsection "The Punishment of Sodomites").

- It emphasises that sodomy was the sin, not homosexuality per se:

  > Sodomy is also approaching a woman from the anus.

  and quotes the hadith:

  > Allah does not look to a man who commits sodomy with a man or a woman. (Reported by At-Tirmidhi. It is good but [Gharib](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7952/what-does-hadith-gharib-%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB-%D8%BA%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A8-mean) hadith)
- A large portion of this section is focused on preventing harm to minors:

  > [AI-Hasan Ibn Zakwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasan_ibn_Ali) said, "Do not be accustomed to sit with the wealthy men's kids since they are good looking like the virgin ladies. They might be more fascinating than women.”
- The closest mention is this:

  > It was narrated from Ibn`Abbas that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
  >
  > Whoever you find doing the action of the people of Lut, kill the one who does it, and the one to whom it is done. [Grade: Hasan (Darussalam)] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/urn/1268780); and [another version](https://sunnah.com/urn/2115030))

  This could be interpreted as implying the [hudd punishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudud) for sodomy, which one might argue implies stoning.

There is a weak hadith not mentioned in Major Sins:

> Narrated [Abdullah ibn Abbas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_Allah_ibn_Abbas):
>
> If a man who is not married is seized committing sodomy, he will be stoned to death.
>
> Abu Dawud said: The tradition of 'Asim proved the tradition of 'Amir b. Abi 'Amr as weak. -- Sunan Abi Dawud 4463 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/113))

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_in_Islam) summarizes the punishment for sodomy in an LGBT context:

> Outside of the Quran, there were varying opinions on how the death penalty was to be carried out for such sexual transgressions. [Abu Bakr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr) apparently recommended toppling a wall on the evil-doer, or else burning alive, while [Ali bin Abi Talib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali) ordered death by stoning for one "luti" and had another thrown head-first from the top of a minaret—according to [Ibn Abbas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_Allah_ibn_Abbas), this last punishment must be followed by stoning. However, according to [Abu Hanifa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Hanifa), homosexual acts are not hadd, but **ta'zeer** (maximum 39 lashes).

Even proponents of punishment for sodomy disagree on the type of punishment.

Comment: "Outside of terrorist organizations, it's hard to find support for stoning." Not true; [pew](http://www.pewglobal.org/2010/12/02/muslims-around-the-world-divided-on-hamas-and-hezbollah/#support-for-severe-laws) finds strong support for stoning among muslims. Among muslims who want sharia to be the law of the land, [there is even more support](http://www.pewforum.org/2013/04/30/the-worlds-muslims-religion-politics-society-beliefs-about-sharia/#penalty-for-adultery). All [countries/regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoning#Usage_today) that officially practice it are muslim-majority.

Comment: @G. Bach: to add a little more detail, Pew says that majorities of muslims in Egypt, Jordan, Pakistan & Nigeria favour harsh punishments such as stoning; whereas in Turkey, Lebanon & Indonesia most oppose. Notably India, which has one of the largest muslim minorities globally & Bangladesh have been left; plus of course muslim minorities in the West.

Comment: @MoziburUllah On the top right of the second Pew link there*s a link to a [complete report](http://www.pewforum.org/files/2013/04/worlds-muslims-religion-politics-society-full-report.pdf), which includes data on Bangladesh; page 221 says 54% of Bangladesh's Muslims were in favor of stoning adulterers, 38% against, 8% declined to answer. The preface says the Muslims of every country with more than 10 million Muslims were polled, "except for a handful (including China, India, Saudi Arabia and Syria) where political sensitivities or security concerns prevented opinion research among Muslims."

Comment: It's not in the Quran, but is it in the shariah?